# Is it possible to post a JSON in JQuery to a server that GET the JSON in Jersey JAVA

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, jersey

Is it even possible to post a JSON in JQuery to a server that GET the JSON in Jersey JAVA,
I'm struggling with the problem. I have a ajax posts a JSON to a server uses Jersey REST GET, but nothing is working, I'm wondering if its the right way to do it.
Here is my previous questions with code regarding to the problem:

code in java implements in the server:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class GetData {
    @GET
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getResource(JSONObject obj) throws IOException {

        InputStream in = (InputStream) obj.values();
        String data = IOUtils.toString(in);

        JSONObject out = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(data);

        String result = out.getString("name");
        return data;
    }                           
}
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '/helloworld',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: { json: JSON.stringify({
            name:"Bob"
        })},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    alert("json posted!");
</script>
```

Message in server console:

> 2012-apr-12 10:49:51 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
>   ALLVARLIG: A message body reader for Java class net.sf.json.JSONObject, and Java type class net.sf.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
>   The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
>   application/octet-stream ->
>     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider

Comment: Include the code and any error messages that causes this not to work - linking to other questions doesnt help - we need to see the code that causes the problem ...

Comment: So to clarify - the problem is that the JavaScript uses `POST` and your Java is reading `GET` ?

Comment: i updated with the problem message now

Comment: @nihulus: HTTP GET assumes that you pass the parameters via URL. Do you really intend to pass JSON string via URL???

Answer (score 1):

As ManseUK implied in the comment, you're sending a POST request and expecting a GET handler to receive it. Either change the `@GET` in the handler to `@POST`, or do something really silly like delegate POST to GET ;)

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getResourceByPost(JSONObject obj) throws IOException {
    return getResource(obj);
}
```

Comment: This will be a eternal recursion when getResource() calls getResource()?
And I'm wondering does the variable obj even contains the json data the has been posted?

Comment: There is no recursion, the @POST annotated method is called `getResourceByPost`. Really, just change your @GET annotation to a @POST